# What about a "linguistics" tag to ask the point of view of the linguistics on an English rule?

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to ask for "linguistics" tag, because sometimes we need the linguistics point of view on English rules, the question is not for the Linguistics SE, because it's specifically about English language,Meta-linguistics tag doesn't always apply,
 and also an "indefinite pronoun" tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your proposal. What is the purpose of this tag, and why can't you categorize your question with one of the tags we already have on the site? I believe tags cover enough topics, and there's even a lot of overlap in some tags, so I can't think of a good use for this [linguistics] tag. Would [sentence-structure] or [syntax] do the job for you?

Comment: I can't organize my question, because I needed a "linguistics" tag, to talk about linguistics applied to the English language. And for the "indefinite pronouns", I think it would be easier to have grammar category, this one: I didn't find it.

Comment: Well, if you mean you want to use a [linguistics] tag because you want to talk about grammar, then you should either use [syntax] or [sentence-structure], because a [linguistics] tag would be pretty useless.

Comment: No, I want to talk about linguistics theory, not only grammar. Not cross-linguistics, but linguistics theory applied to English. Syntax and sentence-structure doesn't fit in my examples, and doesn't show I want a theoretical approach. I don't think it's useless when you need it, if you don't need it, it's otherwise.

Comment: And "indefinite pronouns", because we can browser all the rules for that grammar category.

Comment: If you want a linguist's perspective, then the quetion probably belongs on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) if not Linguistics.SE.

Comment: And on the Linguistics SE, they will tell me it's not about English language grammar. I want a reply to an English grammar question + knowing the point of view of the linguistics about it, applied to the English language only.

Comment: @Quidam If you want a linguistics perspective on a question about English, then [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com) or [Linguistics](http://Linguistics.stackexchange.com) are probably more appropriate anyway.

Comment: I'm really sick of that site where people downvote every question even when "discussion" is mentioned.

Comment: @Quidam I often get downvoted here, but I'm used to it because I believe they downvote my posts for a reason. And I don't think a downvote really hurts you; you are awarded 10 rep for an upvote and only reduced 2 rep for a downvote. And if you feel it still hurts you, you should know the fact that one of the most [downvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949) is from Jeff :)

Comment: @Quidam Downvotes on Meta do not work the same way as downvotes on Main; they indicate disagreement, not quality.

Comment: @choster: That's only really true on *proposals*, but, [tag:discussion] or no, this is in fact a post that makes a proposal. OP: Simply brandishing "discussion" like the sign of the cross doesn't magically prevent people from spotting the fact that you want the site to work a particular way.

Answer (score 10):

Asking for the "linguistics point of view" is ultimately pretty meaningless; there isn't **a** linguistics point of view but **scores** of them: traditional, structuralist, generative, transformational, functional, cognitive, constructionist, minimalist, constituency, phonetics, phonology, historical linguistics, comparative linguistics, sociolinguistics, corpus linguistics, &c.

So if there's something specific you're looking for you will have to specify it. But be warned that there's only a handful of Real Linguists active here (and a slightly larger number of amateurs like me who know how to play a linguist on TV), so the chance of finding someone on ELL who subscribes to any particular linguistic confession is pretty thin.

Aside from that, **all** questions which are on-topic at ELL are [linguistics](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) questions, and to that extent a [linguistics](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) tag would be as pointless as the existing tags [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) and [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

I suspect that what you really mean is that you want to ask a question about usage *X* and get back an answer which doesn't just tell you that *X* is or isn't idiomatic English but provides "theory-based" rules which you can generalize over similar situations. If that's the case, your best bet is to frame your question in a way which calls for generalization. For instance, don't ask this:

> <s>Is this sentence grammatical?</s>
>
> > *X*
>
> Please answer from a linguistics point of view.

Instead, ask it this way:

> The rules I have been taught, *A*, *B* and *C*, suggest that this sentence should be grammatical:
>
> > *X*
>
> But authority *Q* tells me that it is not grammatical. Why do the rules I have learned not apply in this case?

That tells the reader exactly what you want (and incidentally discourages people who can't provide it from cluttering up your life with things you don't want).

Comment: That is a good example of how a question should not written, and how the same question could be better written. I agree that _linguistics_ alone would not make much sense, and the OP should not focus on _linguistics_.